# Using the definition, prove that each function below is continuous on its domain.

Tags: real-analysis

Using the definition, prove that each function below is continuous on its domain. [Be sure to include a description/justification of what the domain is.]

1) $h(t)=\frac{1}{2t+1}$

2) $h(t)=\sqrt{4t+3}$

My thoughts,

1) Domain is all real numbers excluding $\frac{-1}{2}$.

$\left|\frac{1}{2x+1}-\frac{1}{2c+1}\right|< \epsilon$

$\Rightarrow \left|c-x\right|< \epsilon\left|\frac{1}{2}(2x+1)(2c+1)\right|$ But this is where I get stuck.

2) Domain is $x \geq \frac{-3}{4}$.

I am very confused on how to form the $\epsilon - \delta$ proofs of continuity.

Comment: ... have you even *tried* the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definitions? Sure, the intuition is nice, but have you attempted to at least parse the definitions and understand what they mean? Are you struggling at all with that? If so, where?

Comment: Yes I have tried the $\epsilon - \delta$ proofs.  I don't know how to determine the inequalities utilizing $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ without having a point to determine continuity.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're reading the definition backwards: you want to make $|x-c|$ small enough to have $|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$, not the other way around.

For the first one, we want to prove continuity at an arbitrary point $c \neq -1/2$. To get $|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$, at a minimum we need $x$ to not be too close to $-1/2$, because the function blows up near there. Since $x$ will inevitably wind up close to the point $c$ where we are trying to prove continuity, and $c$ itself might actually be pretty close to $-1/2$, we will have to formulate "too close" in terms of $c$.

Let's start by writing

$$\left | \frac{1}{2x+1} - \frac{1}{2c+1} \right | = \left | \frac{2c+1-(2x+1)}{(2x+1)(2c+1)} \right | = \left | \frac{2c-2x}{(2x+1)(2c+1)} \right |.$$

To start with defining this issue of being too close to $-1/2$, let's define $\delta_0=|c-(-1/2)|$. Note that $\delta_0>0$. If $|x-c| \geq \delta_0$ then we have a problem, because $x$ will hit the singularity. Actually, we'd like to be *away* from the singularity by at least a fixed distance, because the function blows up even near the singularity.

To keep $x$ away from the singularity, we can require $|x-c|<\delta_0/2$. This implies that $|x-(-1/2)|>\delta_0/2$, by the reverse triangle inequality.

So $|2x+1|=2|x-(-1/2)|>\delta_0$ and $|2c+1|=2|c-(-1/2)|=2 \delta_0$. So the denominator is at least $2 \delta_0^2$, which is a constant depending only on $c$. Hence

$$\left | \frac{1}{2x+1} - \frac{1}{2c+1} \right | \leq \left | \frac{2c-2x}{2 \delta_0^2} \right |$$

if $|x-c|<\delta_0/2$. So now the proof is just like showing a linear function is continuous. Can you take it from here?